# Search each string in a cell from a data frame and find (match) same string from another data frame column return INDEX to newly prepared dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe 1 (Each term needs to be searched) `'NAN'` means the cell is vacant

```
   0   1   2   

0  AA  BB  NAN 

1  AB  AC  AD
```

Dataframe 2 (Only column 0 have to be matched with each term of Dataframe 1 and return the row index from dataframe 2 and so that we can create a new data frame with row Index information from Datframe 2)

```
  0  
0 AA 
1 AC 
2 AD 
3 AB
```

Results ROW INDEX of DATAFRAME 2 COLUMN 1 .`NA` means string not available in dataframe 2.

```
   0   1   2   

0  0  NA  NAN

1  3   1   2
```

Now another question How can I make the code faster.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the rationale of moving from the input to the output? What's the logic you're trying to implement?

Comment: if columns don't matter just stack, merge & unstack. your result doesn't match your input logic

Comment: What's the rationale behind the values 3-1-2 in the second row of the output?

Comment: @Manakin Yes I have modified my data frame 2. It helps clear the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Roy2012 I have modified the problem statement a little can you please read again?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do that:

```
t = pd.merge(df1.stack().reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), left_on = 0, right_on = "0")
res = t.set_index(["level_0", "level_1"]).drop([0, "0"], axis=1).unstack()
print(res)
```

The output is:

```
        index          
level_1     0    1    2
level_0                
0         0.0  NaN  NaN
1         3.0  1.0  2.0
```

Comment: Thank you but I may not have conveyed my massage.

Comment: Are there any gaps between the output and the expected output?